# Determining height of a block of text in a console application

Tags: c#, console, textblock, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to determine the size of the textframe that will be needed for a block of text. This is to then be exported for an InDesign script to create the page. All in a console application.

I've tried to create a WPF `TextBlock` and assign the `Text` and a `Width`, but the `Height` and `ActualHeight` is NaN.

How can I determine the size of a textframe that will be needed for some text? Is using a WPF / Winforms textblock the best solution (to try and take advantage of existing code), or is there some other, better workflow?

Comment: You may get help faster if you explain better what is *textframe* (I don't know what is `InDesign`). It could be a simple question (as you tagged it with `console`), but I have no clues what are you asking. Can you provide a code? A picture? Something to understand what is the problem? As per WPF `TextBlock`, you can't obtain size until layouting pass. You can try to [force](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) it.

Comment: A textframe is simply a Desktop Publishing term for a box of text. For this example, I simply want to get the needed text block height from a defined text block width for a block of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two classes in C# that are used to draw text. TextRenderer and Graphics.

TextRenderer uses GDI to render the text, whereas Graphics uses GDI+. The two use a slightly different method for laying out text.

You can make use of [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ye7hc8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example

```
using( Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero) )
{
     SizeF size = g.MeasureString("some text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont);
}
```

For your case I would suggest using TextRenderer. Text wrapping example -

```
var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, new Size(width, height), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
```

The third argument is size of the drawing rectangle. You can pass height as `0` if you don't know it.

Comment: I believe neither of these handle text-wrapping though?

Comment: They do. Check TextRenderer overloads. Updated with example.

Comment: Wow, I missed that - great!

Comment: Of course this can only be a best guess, as InDesign's typographic features and layouting are several magnitudes more advanced than GDI.

Comment: I ended up using Graphics.MeasureString because I needed to obtain the resolution for converting the width of the textbox from pixels to inches, and yes; the measurement seems a little out, but is workable.